Using CSS as a selector in jQuery
Trying to overcome an issue with Mobile Safari. I have the following script that changes the class of the container and makes things inside it actionable when someone focuses inside of it:
$(".axxs-accordion .a-section.collapsed").on("focusin", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded");
    $(this).find('a[href], area[href], input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), iframe, object, embed, *[tabindex], *[contenteditable]').removeAttr("inert","");
  });

But apparently, that doesn't work on Mobile Safari. According to the article below, you have to use ":focus-visible" instead:
https://itnext.io/fixing-focus-for-safari-b5916fef1064
So given the above script, how do I edit it so that it includes that workaround?

The article you linked to has a polyfill.  Use that polyfill.

on("focusin" is an event.   :focus-visible is a selector.  They are not the same thing.  You can't change "focusin" to use ":focus-visible".   The polyfill raises those events for you.  Use that polyfill.

The issue is (according to the article) that there's no event fired / to listen to.  So even using event delegation won't work: $(document).on("[no event available]", ".a-section.collapsed:focus-visible", function(.  The polyfill provides that event.
